# 'int' object is not callable. Python

Tags: python

Ошибка вылазит вкупе с двумя строками:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   in 
    min_el(matrix, dvalue, dx, dy)
  in min_el
    str1 = array.ndim(0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
 import numpy as np

post = [int(i) for i in input('Введите поставщиков: ').split()]
potreb = [int(j) for j in input('Введите потребителей: ').split()]
y = len(potreb)
x = len(post)
matrix = np.array([[int(j) for j in input('Цены на перевозку построчно: ').split()] for i in range(x)])
prices = matrix.copy()
values = matrix.copy()

print('Цены на перевозку', prices)


def min_el(array, minvalue = int(), x1 = int(), y1 = int()):
    minvalue = array[0][0]
    x1 = 0
    y1 = 0
    for i in range(0, array.ndim(0)):
        for j in range(0, array.ndim(1)):
            if minvalue > array[i][j]:
                minvalue = array[i][j]
                x1 = i
                y1 = j
    return minvalue, x1, y1


sum1 = int(0)
dvalue = int()
dx = int()
dy = int()

min_el(matrix, dvalue, dx, dy)

while dvalue != 999:
    if post[dx] == 0 | potreb[dy] == 0:
        min_el(matrix, dvalue, dx, dy)
        continue
    if post[dx] >= potreb[dy]:
        values[dx][dy] = potreb[dy]
        potreb[dy] = 0
    else:
        values[dx, dy] = post[dx]
        potreb[dy] = potreb[dy] - post[dx]
        post[dx] = 0
    matrix[dx][dy] = 999
    min_el(matrix, dvalue, dx, dy)


# VALUES
for i in range(0, x):
    for j in range(0, y):
        print('Опорное решение: \n', values[i][j])

# RESULT
for i in range(0, x):
    for j in range(0, y):
        sum1 = sum1 + (values[i][j] * prices[i][j])
print('\n Значение функции: ', sum1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Свойство `ndim` при вызове возвращает количество осей массива, т.е. целое число. Ему не нужны аргументы.
Замените `array.ndim(0)` на `array.ndim`. [Тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/121031/) больше информации.

Comment: жалко, я думала это может быть альтернативой C# - го array.GetLength(...)

Comment: Вы, может знаете как в python можно достать длину определенной строки многомерного массива?

Comment: Можете просто вызывать длину, как для обычного списка в Python. Например, a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) . Тогда длина первой строки, т.е. [1, 2, 3] будет len(a[0]).